# Elasticsearch container empty

Tags: jelastic

I tried two hosters. Massivegrid and Unispace.

On both I created a new environment.

Then choose **docker install**. Choose **elasticsearch**.

After it finished, I took the url ipv4 address and pasted on the browser with port as 9200 and nothing popped up.

So I went into terminal and `netstat` told me there was no elastic service running. In fact nothing related to `elastic` was installed. No `/etc/elasticsearch`.

I used this tutorial https://docs.jelastic.com/elasticsearch

I failed on "Connection via Public IP" part.

Wondering what am I missing.

Edit: I created another new enviorment and installed Elasticsearch 6.8.1 image and this works as per tutorial. The newer range from 7.0 onwards is all blank inside. No Java, no elasticsearch etc.

Answer (score 1):

In order to fix the problem with version 7.2 the next steps can be taken:

1. Add the following string in the `/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh` file:

```
ulimit -n 65536
```

2. And in the `elasticsearch.yml` file (`/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml`) please add:

```
cluster.initial master_nodes: node-1
```

After that restart the container.

Answer (score 1):

Correct setting for `elasticsearch.yml` should look like the following:

```
cluster.initial_master_nodes: node-1
```